# Check if a Path has a trailing slash without allocation

Tags: rust

I need to check if a `Path` has a trailing slash:

##### Solution 1

```
fn has_trailing_slash(p: &Path) -> bool {
    p.to_string_lossy().as_bytes().last() == Some(&b'/')
}
```

**Problem**: this function implies a potential allocation ([`to_string_lossy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_string_lossy)).

##### Solution 2

```
fn has_trailing_slash_unix(p: &Path) -> bool {
    use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt;
    p.as_os_str().as_bytes().last() == Some(&b'/')
}
```

**Problem**: the method [`as_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#impl-OsStrExt) provided by the trait `OsStrExt` is only implemented for Unix and WASI, not for Windows.

##### Question

Is it possible to perform this simple check on a `Path`:

- without useless allocation;
- with a full compatibility on all platforms, including Windows?

Comment: Is this really a performance bottleneck? If not, I would just use `p.to_string_lossy().ends_with('/')` and go on to more important matters. That said, the question is entirely valid of course!

Comment: Frustratingly, `Path` remembers the trailing separator, but carefully ignores it in all the public APIs. So unfortunately it doesn't seem to be currently possible without either (rarely) allocating or writing OS-specific code. See [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/trailing-in-paths/43166) for a discussion.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your comments and for the relevant link.